# my function is invalid and fzero can't handle it

Tags: octave

I get this error

error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @0.1*x - sin(2 * x) + 0.25
error: called from
fzero at line 178 column 6
lab6 at line 82 column 3

Part of code where it happens is:

```
f= '0.1*x - sin(2 * x) + 0.25';
[a, b] = fgraf(f, -3, 3);

fzero(f, [a, b]);
zs1 = ans;
[a, b] = fgraf(f, -3, 3);
zs2 = fzero(f, [a, b]);
[a, b] = fgraf(f, -3, 3);
zs3 = fzero(f, [a, b]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgraf` doesn’t seem to be a standard MATLAB function, so I can’t be sure, but it looks like it expects a function handle as input. Define `f` as

```matlab
f = @(x) 0.1*x - sin(2 * x) + 0.25;
```